# Control number of threads ManagedExecutorService (Java EE Concurrency API) on Wildfly cluster

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, wildfly

Is it possible for Wildfly 9 (domain mode cluster) to controled number of threads for a particular Managed Executor Service on the whole cluster.

In other words to create a Managed Executor Service ((Java EE Concurrency API)) with the fixed number of threads for the whole Wildfly  cluster (wildfly version 9 ) cluster (domain mode).

Comment: See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/EE+Concurrency+Utilities+Configuration

Comment: int the https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/EE+Concurrency+Utilities+Configuration no information about cluster behaviour